# WebDriverException: target frame detached while interacting with elements within iframe using ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I use Chromedriver 78.0.3904.70,

```
WebDriverException: target frame detached exception
```

has occurred, but in previous version of chromedriver all worked fine. 
Now in my iFrame I can't find any elements during the autotest, where should be another iFrame, but i can do it by hand.
Also switching to iFrame doing successfully during autotest. I think may be there is a bug in new chromedriver? Any ideas?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'PDF323-440G4', ip: '172.16.14.147', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de024..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Nikolay\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64307}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: c6f28448e742438746371ee017a51dda
```

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: target frame detached
```

...implies that for a certain **HttpRequest** the resultant **HttpServerResponseInfo** was **`net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND`**.

---

### Details

As per the discussion [Some error codes are not standard compliant](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2552) there were some error codes returned by the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) which were not compliant to the W3C standard. They were replaced with the corresponding standard error codes:

- `asynchronous script timeout` -> **`script timeout`**
- `element not visible` -> **`element not interactable`**
- `no such session` -> **`invalid session id`**
- `session not created exception` -> **`session not created`**
- `xpath lookup error` -> **`invalid selector`**

Additionally, there are some Chrome-specific error codes which still exists and most clients will treat them as **`unknown error`**. These error codes are:

- **`chrome not reachable`**
- **`disconnected`**
- **`forbidden`**
- **`no such execution context`**
- **`tab crashed`**
- **`target frame detached`**

This issue was addressed through the [bug](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97) / [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97) and the current status is **ToBeReleased**.

---

### Deep Dive

The error `target frame detached` is the outcome of [`case kTargetDetached`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/97fe5556deaed6d34e587dbe57cdf12df4f95b97/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/status.cc#75) where `case kTargetDetached` is defined in [`http_handler.cc`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/server/http_handler.cc#993) and occurs when the **HttpServerResponseInfo** contains **HTTP_NOT_FOUND** as follows:

```
void HttpHandler::HandleCommand(
    const net::HttpServerRequestInfo& request,
    const std::string& trimmed_path,
    const HttpResponseSenderFunc& send_response_func) {
  base::DictionaryValue params;
  std::string session_id;
  CommandMap::const_iterator iter = command_map_->begin();
  while (true) {
    if (iter == command_map_->end()) {
      if (w3cMode(session_id, session_thread_map_)) {
    PrepareResponse(
        trimmed_path, send_response_func,
        Status(kUnknownCommand, "unknown command: " + trimmed_path),
        nullptr, session_id, true);
      } else {
    std::unique_ptr<net::HttpServerResponseInfo> response(
        new net::HttpServerResponseInfo(net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND));
    response->SetBody("unknown command: " + trimmed_path, "text/plain");
    send_response_func.Run(std::move(response));
      }
      return;
    }
    if (internal::MatchesCommand(
        request.method, trimmed_path, *iter, &session_id, &params)) {
      break;
    }
    ++iter;
  }
```

and most possibly the reason in your case is [`kTargetDetached`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/server/http_handler.cc#1171):

```
case kTargetDetached:
  response.reset(new net::HttpServerResponseInfo(net::HTTP_NOT_FOUND));
  break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue on Version 79. Updated to chrome Version 80.0.3987.53 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on my mac machine and used chromedriver version 80.0.3987.16 while working with selenium. Switching to iframe is working fine now.

[image]

Got a hint from the above point that it has been fixed in version 80. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

May not be correct or optimal solution but after adding Thread.sleep and nested try catch block issue got resolved.
Note: in WebDriverException I tried the same element again

```
    try
    {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    yourWebelement.click();
    }
    catch(WebDriverException e)
    {
        yourWebelement.click();
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        throw ee;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can use a try and catch block for the elements in which this error occurs - and the tests will continue further without stopping

```
try {

button.click();

} catch (WebDriverException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when my **Selenium driver** version **mismatched** the version of my **Chrome browser** because I updated my web browser to its last version without updating also the Selenium driver.

I fixed the issue by updating also my selenium web driver to match the updated chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I get this error when I have too many instances of ChromeDriver running.

I have an application that attempts to shut down instances of ChromeDriver when I am done with current tests, but when I see this error, I usually find that I have 10-20 instances running because I was debugging some issue, and not letting the clean-up code run.

Open Task Manager and kill old instances!

Answer (score 0):

This issue may also happen when the system resources are low. I had the same issue in a machine where memory, disk and cpu often used to go to 100%. Tried in a different machine with higher capacity. It worked without any issue.