# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached error using Selenium and Chromedriver via Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing by parsing program using Python and Selenium.

There is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Desktop/babushkabot.py", line 123, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 658, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users//Desktop/babushkabot.py", line 61, in callback_inline_tomato
    driver.get(url[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 437, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.75)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001053db3d9 chromedriver + 5104601
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010536bbf3 chromedriver + 4647923
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f5c9ff chromedriver + 391679
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f47a5c chromedriver + 305756
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f46b6a chromedriver + 301930
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f4706c chromedriver + 303212
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f46fc4 chromedriver + 303044
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f4dc82 chromedriver + 330882
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f4df42 chromedriver + 331586
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f48358 chromedriver + 308056
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f48918 chromedriver + 309528
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f486ca chromedriver + 308938
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f47c67 chromedriver + 306279
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f47423 chromedriver + 304163
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f637fa chromedriver + 419834
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000104fc249d chromedriver + 808093
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000104faf5b3 chromedriver + 730547
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f85139 chromedriver + 557369
18  chromedriver                        0x0000000104f86165 chromedriver + 561509
19  chromedriver                        0x000000010539a39d chromedriver + 4838301
20  chromedriver                        0x00000001053b2cde chromedriver + 4938974
21  chromedriver                        0x00000001053b7b5e chromedriver + 4959070
22  chromedriver                        0x00000001053b394a chromedriver + 4942154
23  chromedriver                        0x000000010538f33c chromedriver + 4793148
24  chromedriver                        0x00000001053cd3b8 chromedriver + 5047224
25  chromedriver                        0x00000001053cd53f chromedriver + 5047615
26  chromedriver                        0x00000001053e2705 chromedriver + 5134085
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff800b55514 _pthread_start + 125
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff800b5102f thread_start + 15
```

Version of Chrome driver is 100.0.4896.60
Version of Google Chrome 100.0.4896.75

If someone could help me to resolve this question, gonna be awesome!

Comment: You should share some code so we can help you more efficiently

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check for multiple instances of running ChromeDriver. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73602462/228601

Answer (score 0):

*`target frame detached`* error occurs when the *HttpServerResponseInfo* contains *`HTTP_NOT_FOUND`* and a couple of approaches to address this error are as follows:

- To switch Selenium's [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()` as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframeCssSelector")))
  ```
- Ensure that as you are using *chrome=100.0.4896.75* you have downloaded and configured the matching [*chromedriver=100.0.4896.60*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/)