# selenium python can't perform click event

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need to click each of variation in this page.

My code clicking on first element but I am getting error when it trying to click on second element. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = 'https://www.zzounds.com/item--RNESEVENTYTWOMK2?siid=320037'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

click = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-button")
for i in click:
    text = i.text
    print(text)
    i.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

error which I am getting when trying to click on second element:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.62)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836020/webdriverexception-target-frame-detached-while-interacting-with-elements-within

Comment: If you are performing a click action in your loop, you are probably reloading the page and losing the elements. You would need to find the elements again after the page loads.

Comment: Check out some of the answers to this thread, might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836020/webdriverexception-target-frame-detached-while-interacting-with-elements-within